# What is a word for a person being "crossways"?

Tags: single-word-requests

In my native language Swedish we say that a person is "tvär" if he is diffcult to agree with. It literally means "blocker" i.e. tvär would mean "på tvären" (on the crossway) that means that the person is very difficult or impossible to agree with.

Comment: I don't think you're right about that.

Comment: @Robusto Now I think that you are nothing but contrary and disagreeable.

Comment: Well, some of these comments, well, they got me quite crossways. But the sun is quite kind.

Comment: @RegDwigнt it's for people like you, we keep it turned on...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use "contrary" - meaning: they always take the opposing view.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say such a person is **disagreeable**. They may argue against you out of spite, just for the sake of disagreeing.

OED
adj.

Not in agreement; characterized by difference or incongruity; disagreeing, discordant, at variance.

Answer (score 1):

**bloody-minded** (*adj., British informal*):

1. someone who is bloody-minded makes things difficult for others and opposes their views for no good reason

> '*He's just being bloody-minded.*'

Source: [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/bloody-minded)

2. Deliberately refusing to accept that you are not completely right about something, in a way that is not helpful to other people and annoys them

Source: [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/bloody-minded)